# upsells in custom Magento template

Tags: magento

The template I am using does not display upsell products as of now. Does anyone know where the associated files are? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the `catalog/product/view.phtml` template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

That should add upsells back.

Thanks,
Joe